# Upscaled Output image color different from Orginal

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I've converted Real-ESRGAN-x44-general onnx to tflite. But getting different color output.

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3UO7.jpg)

[output_image_before_conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN9K7.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ccnN.jpg)

The code i tried:

```
import tensorflow.lite as tflite
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

# Define the paths for the model and the image.
model_path = "realesr-general-x4v3_float32.tflite"
input_image_path = 'input.jpg'
output_image_path = 'output_image.jpg'

# Check if the image file exists.
if not os.path.exists(input_image_path):
    raise Exception(f"Error: Input image path '{input_image_path}' does not exist.")

# Load the TensorFlow Lite model.
interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get the input and output details.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Load and preprocess the image.
input_image = cv2.imread(input_image_path)
input_image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(input_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
input_image_resized = cv2.resize(input_image_rgb, tuple(input_details[0]['shape'][1:3]))
# Skip normalization to see if that's where the issue is
input_image_normalized = input_image_resized.astype(np.float32) / 255.0

# Set the input tensor without normalization
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], [input_image_normalized])

# Run inference.
interpreter.invoke()

# Get the output results.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
output_image = np.squeeze(output_data)

# Assuming the model outputs in a [0, 1] range, denormalize if necessary.
# If the model output is not in this range, this step may need to be adjusted.
output_image_denormalized = (output_image * 255.0).astype(np.uint8)

# Save the image before color conversion to check the raw output.
cv2.imwrite('output_image_before_conversion.jpg', output_image_denormalized)

# Convert the output image from RGB to BGR for consistency with OpenCV's saving function.
output_image_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(output_image_denormalized, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

# Save the image after color conversion to check the final output.
cv2.imwrite(output_image_path, output_image_bgr)

# Print a success message.
print(f"Output image saved successfully to '{output_image_path}'.")
```

Why is this happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: Post a [mre] including the conversion procedure from the pth to tflite format. Anyway, it seems they don't care TFLite. Why not try Ncnn which they care. See [this](https://github.com/xinntao/Real-ESRGAN/blob/master/docs/ncnn_conversion.md).